# Showing and hiding sections with CSS based on a drop-down option

Tags: html, css, hide, html-select

Iam using a rather neat example where a user hid sections based on the input from radio buttons, listed below:

CSS:

```
div[class^="section"] {     
    display: none;
}

input.choose-a:checked ~ div.section-a,
input.choose-b:checked ~ div.section-b,
input.choose-c:checked ~ div.section-c {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="choose-a" name="sectionselect"/>
<input type="radio" class="choose-b" name="sectionselect"/>
<input type="radio" class="choose-c" name="sectionselect"/>
<div class="section-a">Section A content</div>
<div class="section-b">Section B content</div>
<div class="section-c">Section C content</div>
```

I would like to, however, show and hide sections based on a drop down list's currently selected option. So, naturally, I tried:

CSS:

```
div[class^="section"] {     
    display: none;
}

option.choose-a:checked ~ div.section-a,
option.choose-b:checked ~ div.section-b,
option.choose-c:checked ~ div.section-c {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option class="choose-a">option A</option>
    <option class="choose-b">option B</option>
    <option class="choose-c">option C</option>
</select>
<div class="section-a">Section A content</div>
<div class="section-b">Section B content</div>
<div class="section-c">Section C content</div>
```

Which didn't seem to work. Yet [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) seems to suggest that ':checked' does indeed function on an option. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: _I'm working on a silly project_ that' the spirit:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `<div>` is not sibling of `<option>`, but `<select>`. And in CSS, there is no *parent* selector. So I'm afraid it's not possible with dropdown.